# what's the best way to convert a OpenOffice (odp) file to HTML?

Tags: html, export, openoffice.org

i already have read about how to do this and the different methods, but:
it is worth parsing the xml code inside the odp file? (ex. with PHP)
or better with the help of a extern script (eg. python) and the OO api?
what's the best solution to do this kind of job?
what i mean with this question is about performance, security (executing a extern script with php maybe?), and efford (in case of the first question)
if there is a better way, i would be glad to hear about it